# P8H67-M: won't boot from cloned disk

Tags: boot, motherboard

Given: a computer based upon ASUS P8H67-M motherboard.

I have 4 HDDs, used in RAID (attached to 4 3GB/s ports) and one boot disk (attached to a 6Gb/s port).

The boot disk started to generate bad (reallocated) blocks, so I decided to clone it to a sane drive and replace. 320Gb Seagate was cloned to 1Tb WD disk (CloneZilla + Rescatux).

The problem: the cloned drive boots fine on any other computer but this one. OS is CentOS 6.2, if that does matter. BIOS remains at logo screen (offering to press 'Del' to enter setup), and only responds to Ctrl-Alt-Del at that moment.

If I place the old drive back, it boots fine without any problems.